# SQL, Select from table A and use result ID to loop though table B?

Tags: sql, while-loop

I have a windows server running MS-SQL 2008.

I have a customer table that I need to select the id's of all customers that are Active, On Hold, or Suspended.

get all customers that are Y= current active customer H=on hold S=Suspended

```
select id from customer where active = 'Y';
```

the above statement worked fine for selecting the ID's of the affected customers.

I need to use these results to loop though the following command in order to find out what rates all the affected customers have.

get all rates for a customer

```
select rgid from custrate where custid = [loop though changing this id with results from first statement];
```

the id from the customer table coincides with the custid from the custrate table.

So in the end I need a list of all affected customer id's and what rgid's(rate group(s)) they have.

Comment: NEVER think of looping through records, that is the way to have badly performing systems. You need to think in terms of data sets not individual records. This is something you need to learn before you are qualified to query a database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL isn't about loops in general and instead you should think in terms of joins.

```
select customer.id, custrate.rgid, customer.active
from customer
inner join custrate
  on customer.id = custrate.custid
where active in ('Y', 'H', 'S")
order by customer.active, customer.id
```

would be a starting point to think about. However, that is just a wild guess as the schema was not specified nor the relations between the tables.

Comment: Both tables sit inside the same Database.  The only thing that the tables have in common is the id from the customer table coincides with the custid of the custrate table... I know sql doesn't loop anything like most other language syntax.  Hence the reason why I'm confused with this issue.  Is there other info that I could provide that would help explain the schema?

Comment: the rgid is not in the customer table only the custrate table so unless I don't understand the syntax you posted I don't think it will work but ill go check.

Comment: If you know the linking ID is customer.id = custrate.custid, then the syntax provided should work for your requirement (customer IDs and RateIDs). If it doesn't, providing the table structures (or subsets) would help. Note that above I don't assume rgid is in the customer table, but instead called out custrate.rgid in the select.

Comment: OK Sweet thanks!... How could I run the first select statement so that I only get customers that have Y,H,or S in the active column of the customer table?  select customer.id where active = 'Y', custrate.rgid FROM ...?  I could run it three times for Y, H, S that would be fine

Comment: You would add a WHERE clause. I have edited my answer to include a guess at what you are looking for. I would point out this is absolute basics and if you need to do this with any frequency I would recommend seeking a book on beginning SQL. SQL server comes with "Books Online" which is the help system... it is quite comprehensive.

Comment: @snowkiterdude, you should not need to run the same selct 3 times, you need to stop thinking of loops. Loops are VERY BAD in Sql.

Comment: @HLGEM Your right I have only use php to parse sql in the past and need to break that thought process and learn the correct syntax for more advanced statements like this.

Comment: You can close this question as answered by clicking the checkbox. That will take it off the unanswered list.